# Evaluate the following definite integral $\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^4+10x^2+9}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Evaluate the following definite integral: $$\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^4+10x^2+9}dx$$
I have factored top and bottom and notice nothing factors out. I thought this would be an easy integration but i am in need of guidance.

Comment: partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the residue theorem:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x^4+10x^2+9}\,dx = 2\pi i\left(\mathop{\rm Res}_{x=i}\frac{x^2+3x+2}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}+\mathop{\rm Res}_{x=3i}\frac{x^2+3x+2}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}\right) = 2\pi i\left(\frac{-1+3i+2}{2i\cdot8}+\frac{-9+9i+2}{-8\cdot6i}\right) = \frac{5\pi}{12}$$

Answer (score 6):

Try integrating the indefinite integral by partial fractions.

That is, find $A,B,C,D$ such that
$$
\dfrac{Ax+B}{x^2+9}+\dfrac{Cx+D}{x^2+1}=\dfrac{x^2-3x+2}{x^4+10x^2+9}
$$

It should be easy to integrate the individual $\dfrac{Ax+B}{x^2+9}$ and $\dfrac{Cx+D}{x^2+1}$